# Spring webflux and Angular

Tags: angular, spring-webflux, reactive

I developed a spring boot 2 with webflux backend and now I have to integrate the frontend part. My handler return a Flux using paging.
What i can't understand is how frontend could know about the number of pages available. If I return Page I have all the information needed, but with flux?
I can't do a count before because it's against the reactive programming. so how can I manage a "reactive pagination" in frontend side?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `Pageable` in your Spring Boot app you'll have some helpful metadata in your response as:

- The pages number
- Rows in each page
- The current page
- ...etc

So like that with using some tools in the frontend you'll be able to navigate between pages.

Comment: I already used Pageable but i cannot here. If i use Pageable i have to wait till all the item of the page are retrieved. And this isn't usefull if I use a reactive paradigm

Comment: you can always return the number of pages available at the time of sending the flux, by providing metadata that tells you the current number of pages.

Comment: The problem is this. I don't know how to return metadata. if I have Flux<MyObject> as return type, how can i send metadata? I don't think so, but can I know the number of pages without do a count operation before?